# How to set dfferent fixed columns datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I would like to set fixed columns on scroll with data tables, say I have a column at index 1,10,15. On horizontal scroll, I need to be able to set those as fixed. At the moment I am only able to set only the first column to be fixed.

1. Work for the first column

   ```
   $('#example').DataTable( {
   fixedColumns: true
   ```

   } );
2. Works for the first two columns

   $('#example').DataTable( {
               fixedColumns: {
                   leftColumns: 2
               }
           } );

How do I fix the 1,10,15

I tried

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: [1,10,15]
    }
} );
```

Example

```
 table columns = > |1(freeze) | 2 |... |10(freeze)|....|15(freeze)|
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Datatable's Doc](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)

You can add Fixed Columns in both Left and Right and it even allows multiple Columns.

Catch is all columns have to be continous.

Unfortunately fixing column in middle is not allowed. Due to its complexity. Read Doc above

**Sample Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatbleId').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2,
            rightColumns: 3
        }
    } );
} );
```

More detail [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html)

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omgLswq6/210/)

Answer (score 1):

You might try this to fix the column in your js .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
} );
```